# Setting Datacontext in a view and grabbing it inside the view file

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I currently have this setup:

My main window contains this

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <view:SymbolListView DataContext="{Binding Path=SymbolListViewModel}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    <view:SymbolTabView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <view:SymbolView/>
</DockPanel>
```

Where i have the following inside my viewmodel

```
public SymbolListViewModel SymbolListViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SymbolListViewModel = new SymbolListViewModel();
    }
```

But then inside my SymbolListView i need to grap the previously set datacontext and use it. This however does not seem to work.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Symbols}">
```

This line inside the SymbolListView is trying to bind to the mainViewModel instead of the given context of SymbolListViewModel. If i read the following error correctly that is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Symbols' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=66824994)'. BindingExpression:Path=Symbols; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=66824994); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

I'm sure this is a newbie mistake but i can't seem to find my error.
Please send help!

Thanks!

Comment: As a note, if the MainViewModel constructor is the only place where the SymbolListViewModel property is set, you should make the property readonly: `public SymbolListViewModel SymbolListViewModel { get; } = new SymbolListViewModel();`. Otherwise it should raise a property change notification event.

Comment: That said, are you sure you do not accidentially somewhere set the SymbolListView's DataContext to an instance of MainViewModel? The error message looks like you'd do that.

Comment: I've just triple checked the SymbolListView.xaml and cs and i do not use mainview anywhere. id use datacontext in my OnLoaded method where i write the datacontext to the console and it gives me: NolekSymbols.ViewModel.SymbolListViewModel
This seems to be the datacontext i want but the symbols still doesnt show and the error persists

Also i've made the model readonly. Thanks!